# Mysql error on Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am trying to export a csv file after a mysql query. I get the following error;

(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1")

```
    import csv

from django.db import connections

from django.http import HttpResponse

from django.views.generic import ListView

from testing.models import TrRunSummary, TrDetails


class ExportCsv(ListView):
    """Displays the different tests performed on the specified test request"""
    template_name = 'testing/tr_export_csv.html'
    context_object_name = 'export_csv'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ExportCsv,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tr_info'] = self.tr_info()

        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qtr_id = self.kwargs['trID']
        s = str(qtr_id)
        print s
        print type(s)



 cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    query ="SELECT results_stb_id, results_stbs.stb_id, stb_inv.mac_add, "
    "test_functionality.test_functionality_code, test_cases.test_case_no, "
    "SCRIPT.option_name AS script_result, POST.option_name AS post_result, "
    "results_tests.started, results_tests.stopped, results_tests.test_duration, builds.baseline, "
    "builds.build_type, stb_hw_info.stb_type, defects.defect_name, parser_output, log_url, "
    "script_health_score, post_health_score FROM results_stbs "
    "JOIN tr_test_cases "
    "ON tr_test_cases.tr_test_case_id=results_stbs.tr_test_case_id "
    "JOIN test_cases "
    "ON test_cases.test_case_id=tr_test_cases.test_case_id "
    "JOIN test_functionality "
    "ON test_functionality.test_functionality_id=test_cases.test_functionality_id "
    "LEFT JOIN stb_inv "
    "ON results_stbs.stb_id=stb_inv.stb_id "
    "LEFT JOIN result_options AS SCRIPT "
    "ON results_stbs.script_result=SCRIPT.result_option_id "
    "LEFT JOIN result_options AS POST "
    "ON results_stbs.post_result=POST.result_option_id "  
    "JOIN results_tests "
    "ON results_stbs.results_test_id=results_tests.results_test_id "
    "JOIN builds "
    "ON builds.build_id=results_stbs.build_id "
    "JOIN stb_hw_info_ids "
    "ON stb_hw_info_ids.stb_hw_info_ids_id=results_stbs.stb_hw_info_ids_id "
    "JOIN stb_hw_info "
    "ON stb_hw_info.stb_hw_info_id=stb_hw_info_ids.stb_hw_info_id "
    "LEFT JOIN defects_tests "
    "ON results_tests.results_test_id=defects_tests.results_test_id "
    "LEFT JOIN defects "
    "ON defects.defect_id=defects_tests.defect_id "
    "WHERE tr_test_cases.tr_id = '%s' AND script_result IN (1, 3, 8) " 
    "OR tr_test_cases.tr_id = '%s' AND post_result IN (1, 3, 8) "
    "ORDER BY results_stb_id ASC " % (s, s)


        cursor.execute(query)

        print cursor



    def tr_info(self):
        tr_id = self.kwargs['trID']
        tr_info = TrDetails.objects.get(
            tr_id=tr_id,
        )
        return tr_info



class SavedCsvView(ExportCsv):
    """
    Subclass of above view, to produce a csv file
    """
    template_name = 'TR_Export.csv'
    content_type = 'text/csv'
```

My query works fine on Python Script. When I add on the django views, it gives me error. Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: please paste the full traceback for error

Comment: you can execute the direct sql query in this manner https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

Comment: Terminate the lines with the strings with `\` or use triple quotation marks or surround everything after the`=` with `()` to create a multi-line string. How you did it only the first part gets into the string.

Comment: Hi @KlausD. Thanks for your helps. Parentheses help me to solve the issue. So, how I can  run this query to export csv file ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: here is the whole documentation on how to save django response in csv and even steam it over http https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/

Comment: Why drag django into this???

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Klaus D in comments

> Terminate the lines with the strings with `or use triple quotation
>   marks or surround everything after the=` with () to create a
>   multi-line string. How you did it only the first part gets into the
>   string. – Klaus D.

you should fix the query string using `<tripple quotes> """<query>"""`.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    ...
    query = """SELECT results_stb_id, results_stbs.stb_id, stb_inv.mac_add,
        test_functionality.test_functionality_code, test_cases.test_case_no,
        SCRIPT.option_name AS script_result, POST.option_name AS post_result,
    ..."""
    cursor.execute(query)
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return row
```

How to return query response cursor from a direct sql query on db, Refer doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly

and this example : http://blog.appliedinformaticsinc.com/how-to-perform-raw-sql-queries-in-django/

OP added another question in comments

> Hi @KlausD. Thanks for your helps. Parentheses help me to solve the
>   issue. So, how I can run this query to export csv file ? Thanks a lot
>   :)

To export query response to csv, there are multiple options:

One is straight forward django approach [reference] https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/outputting-csv/

Another is to use this library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-queryset-csv/

Which is very simple to use

```
from djqscsv import render_to_csv_response

def csv_view(request):
    qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar=True).values('id', 'bar')
    return render_to_csv_response(qs)
```

if you want to just write to csv use this:

```
from djqscsv import write_csv

qs = Foo.objects.filter(bar=True).values('id', 'bar')
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    write_csv(qs, csv_file)
```